# Python regex: Subsentence that contains number which can have thousand separator and decimal

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text. I would like to collect all subsentences (from comma or period to comma or period) that have a number in them. I have managed to create the following regex that collects the number and the part after it, but since my number can have commas or periods inside it I don't know how I can grab the words before it.The sentence with the parts I would like to get in bold:

> In connection with the consummation of this offering, we will enter
> into a forward purchase agreement with OrION Capital Structure
> Solutions UK Limited, or OrION, an affiliate of our sponsor, **pursuant
> to which OrION will commit that it will purchase from us 10,000,000
> forward purchase units**, **or at its option up to an aggregate maximum of
> 30,000,000 forward purchase units**, each consisting of one Class A
> ordinary share,or a forward purchase share, and one-third of one
> warrant to purchase one Class A ordinary share, **or a forward purchase
> warrant, for $10.00 per unit**, **or an aggregate amount of $100,000,000**,
> **or at OrION’s option up to an aggregate amount of $300,000,000**, in a
> private placement that will close concurrently with the closing of our
> initial business combination.

What I want to collect:

```
["pursuant to which OrION will commit that it will purchase from us 10,000,000 forward purchase units",
"or at its option up to an aggregate maximum of 30,000,000 forward purchase units", "for $10.00 per unit", "or an aggregate amount of $100,000,000", "or at OrION’s option up to an aggregate amount of $300,000,000"]
```

The regex I wrote currently gets the number and the part after until the next comma or period.

```
[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?.*?[\.,]
```

How can I collect part of the sentence (starting with a period or comma), and the number that can have a decimal or thousand separator in it and then part of the sentence until the next comma or period?

EDIT: anubhava and bb1 both give the correct solution. anubhava solved the question exactly as I have asked it and it is the correct answer. bb1 however prepares for something that is bound to happen (and I did not think of) so in the end I used his answer, but marked anubhava as the one who gave the solution because that is the exact solution that i have asked.

EDIT 2: anubhava since updated his answer so it solves the same problem as bb1-s.

Comment: Incorrect dupe. This problem is different and not even one answer in dupe answer is a solution of current problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex with look-around assertions:

```sh
(?<=[.,] )(?:[^,.]*?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)+[^.,]*(?=[,.])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsJd12/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=[.,] )`: Lookbehind assertion to assert that we have comma or dot followed by a space before the current position
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `[^,.]*?`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `,` and `.` (lazy)
  - `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*`: Match a number that may contain `.` or `,`
- `)+`: End non-capture group. `+` repeats this group 1+ times
- `[^.,]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `,` and `.`
- `(?=[,.])`: Lookahead assertion to assert that we have comma or dot after the current position

Comment: Yes and it is exactly what I have asked for. Thank you!

Comment: Seeing your comment on other answer I realize you may have cases where there are multiple numbers per sentence. Hence I have updated my answer slightly to address that case as well.

Comment: Thank you, I know that i might not have stated it but updating it will make sure that everyone copies the more robust answer later on.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of anubhava works very well provided that there is one number in a string segment enclosed by commas or periods, but does not cover the case when there are multiple numbers e.g.

```
"Therefore, this costs $10,000 and that costs $20,000 per item."
```

In case it is helpful here is a version which deals with such cases:

```
(?<=[,.])(?:[^,.]*?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*[^,.]*?)+(?=[,.])
```

Comment: That is actually something I have not considered before. I am not yet familiar with stackoverflow customs that much, in the end I've marked anubhavas answer as the solution because it is what exactly solves the question as stated. However in the end it was yours that I have used because it prepares for something that is bound to happen and I did not think of. I'll state this in the question.